# Advice about sharing resources for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

My company is slowly moving over to silverlight (from strictly asp.net apps) for our business enterprise. We have several large scale, web based applications, and different teams of developers work on the different products. Even though the products, and therefore the projects/solutions are separate, we do need to have some things in common. While data structures are definitely one of those things, my question today is about UI resources, such as common color themes, logos, styles, custom controls,localization, etc. I want to make sure that if make a change in one place, that the change will propagate to all our applications as seamlessly as possible.

Obviously (to me) App.xaml is the place to put most of these resources, however that still only covers one project, unless we make sure to import the same App.xaml into every project in every solution, and then provide a way to update that file (such as a link to it) when it changes. This sounds a little messy.

I'm wondering if anyone else has had to tackle this problem, and if you could share your techniques or ideas? Can any of these be stored in a database? In the cloud? Can it be easily stored in a *.dll and added to each project? How did you approach it?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is to put all your resources in one particular assembly and reference that assembly from your resource dictionary in app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/AltinetSilver;component/AltiStyles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/AltiStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>                
</Application.Resources>
```

The first ResourceDictionary is from Assembly altinetSilver and it takes AltiStyles.xaml. The second one is the regular one. So i think that should cover it.